# formatting a toshiba external hard drive for mac and pc

Tags: hard-drive

I tried to format my Toshiba external hard drive to accept Asus pc and MacBook air files. I removed everything from the hard drive, put it on my pc.  I used the format MS DOS (FAT} on the mac and erased the hard drive. All was well till I plugged it into the Asus and now I can not open the hard drive to put the files back on it.  It shows it is there but does not open.  Just want to add that I used time machine on the mac and I believe that is causing the problem. I would really just like my files from the pc back on the hard drive.  What should I do? Erase everything and start over? Is it possible to make the mac and pc compatible on the hard drive. I am not computer savvy and would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you format is as "FAT" then you'll have lots of issues with the size of files you can write to it and other filesystem limitations. Best bet is to format it on the PC as Fat32 or even better exFAT on the Mac.

Both of those will give you read/write capability on both the Mac and PC. Just remember tho when you first plug it into the Mac wait for Time Machine to pop up the question about using the drive to do backups. Say no and it won't bother you again.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked.  I formatted the HD using exfat on the mac  and then could open it up on my Asus pc to transfer photos onto it. That was the most important thing to be done because my asus is not working properly and I did not want to lose the photos. Then I went back to the Mac and put the Mac photos on the HD.  Then I went to the Asus to see if the Mac photos would come up My one questions is when I went to erase I had to choose GUID partition map, master boot or apple partition. I used master boot.

Comment: Sorry hit the wrong button and sent before corrections......Then I went to the Asus to see if the Mac photos would come up but they did not show up. So I went back to Mac, disconnected the internet, checked on the HD and the mac photos are there.  So I do not care about them not showing up on the pc because I will not use it anymore.  So My one questions is when I went to erase HD on the Mac I had to choose GUID partition map, master boot or apple partition. I used master boot, was that the correct one and is this why they are not showing up on the pc?  Sorry if this is confusing,

Comment: Unless you are going to boot from that HD the partition map does not make a difference. MBR is an older standard GUID is the newer one (and the one you use if you want to boot a modern Macintosh). In your use case you will not notice the difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your help!   Everything is just the way I want it!!

Comment: Cool, if you could mark it ans the answer, that would be great!